Remove extra bibliography title from the list of sections
I have this presentation:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib/bibliografia.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{shadow}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{Sección \thesection}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{frame}{Frame 1}
        My cite.\cite{testbib}
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Section References}
    \begin{frame}{Frame References}     
        \nocite{testbib}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}

It shows an extra title in the index (at the top). How can I make it dissapear?


You can use \printbibliography[heading=none] to prevent biblatex from starting a new section:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{shadow}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{Sección \thesection}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Frame 1}
        My cite.\cite{knuth:ct}
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Section References}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Frame References}     
        \printbibliography[heading=none]
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}


